# How to add target to form in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to add target to form.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'Adres email'),'attr' => array('class' => 'class_name'))}
```

In controller I use:

```
$Register = new Register();

$form = $this->createForm(new RegisterType(), $Register);
$form -> handleRequest($Request);
```

Answer (score 0):

just pasting some code i use, i defined the formType as service with tag "review" for my Review Entity, heres my controller action

```
$review = new Review();
$form = $this->createForm('review',$review);
$request = $this->getRequest();

// only handle request if form is submitted
if ('POST' === $request->getMethod()) {
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $entity=$form->getData();

        try {
            $saved=$this->myService->saveReview($entity);    
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $form->addError(new FormError($e->getMessage()));
            return array(
                "form"=>$form->createView()
            );
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('some.url',array("some","mandatory-params")));
    }
}
return array(
    "form"=>$form->createView(),
);
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_form_type_extension.html